# Titanium iOS camera - showCamera error

Tags: ios, titanium

I'm using Titanium and testing the camera on iOS.  I'm getting an issue where code after the camera page is being run before I've gone through the camera page.  In the below code, the line `'alert('Picture uploaded successfully.')` is executed before the camera screen has even opened up..  Any ideas?

```
    var wincam;

wincam = Titanium.UI.createWindow();
if (Ti.Platform.osname === 'android') {
    win.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
    });
} else {

Titanium.Media.showCamera({

    success:function(event)
    {
        var cropRect = event.cropRect;
        var image = event.media;

        Ti.API.debug('Our type was: '+event.mediaType);
        if(event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO)
        {
            var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                width:win.width,
                height:win.height,
                image:event.media
            });
            win.add(imageView);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("got the wrong type back ="+event.mediaType);
        }
    },
    saveToPhotoGallery:false,
    allowEditing:true,
    mediaTypes:[Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO,Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO]
});

}
            //open next page
            var w3 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
                backgroundImage:'/images/5-survey.png'
            });
            w3.open();

            alert('Picture uploaded successfully.');
```

Answer (score 0):

showCamera is an asynchronous event it does not stop the execution context. If you want an alert on the successful capture of an image, put the alert in the success event.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/144053/showcamera-issue-on-ios#answer-250088
— answered 1 hour ago by Anthony Decena